# Uniform convergence on compact sets allows switching the limit and the integral.

Tags: limits, compactness, uniform-convergence

Why does uniform convergence on compact sets allows switching the limit and the integral?

Comment: Do you mean how to prove it, or why is it true in a big-picture sor t of way, or are you asking for the theorem that justifies it?

Comment: Both would be nice- But I'd like the theorem especially.

Comment: Can you include an example of what kind of applications you have in mind? That would help sharpen this question.

Comment: Ugh I didn't want to whip out the LaTeX. 
Given a sequence of analytic functions $\{f_{n}\}_{n}$ on a domain D, suppose $\sum_{n} f_{n}$ converges at least normally on D. Then $F = \sum_{n} f_{n}$ is analytic on D and $F^{(k)} = \sum_{n} f^{(k)}_{n}.$ 

Given a path $\Gamma \subset D$, then  $\displaystyle\int_{\Gamma} \sum_{n} f_{n} \, dz = \sum_{n} \displaystyle\int_{\Gamma} f_{n} \, dz.$

Comment: It was with regard to the last line.

Answer (score 3):

In integral; if $f_n\to f$ uniformly on the compact $K$, then 
$|\int_Kf_n-\int_Kf|=|\int_K(f_n-f)|\leq \|f_n-f\|_{K}\int_K1\to 0$, hence
$\int_Kf_n\to \int_Kf$.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Hamou's answer:

Suppose that a sequence $\{f_n\}$ of functions on a compact set is such that $f_n \to f$ uniformly.  We can then state that for any $\epsilon>0$, there is an $N$ such that $\sup_{K}|f(x) - f_n(x)| < \epsilon/(\int_K 1\,dx)$ whenever $n>N$.  It follows that for $n>N$, we have
$$
\left|\int_K f(x)\,dx - \int_K f_n(x)\,dx \right| =
\left|\int_K (f(x)- f_n(x))\,dx \right| \\
\leq \int_K |f(x)- f_n(x)|\,dx\\
\leq \int_K \frac{\epsilon}{\int_K 1\,dx}\,dx = \epsilon
$$
Thus, we conclude that
$$
\int_K f_n(x)\,dx \to  \int_K f(x)\,dx
$$
as $n \to \infty$.

Uniform convergence allows us to bound $f_n - f$, and compactness allows us to compute $\int_K 1\,dx$.

Comment: Can we take each $fn$ to be continuous instead of domain to be compact?